# Freeradius 3.0.11 Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, radius, freeradius

I'm trying to configure freeradius 3.0.11 with postgresql but I'm having an issue with the driver listed in the sql file inside of 'mods-enabled.' The driver I am listing is 'rlm_sql_postgresql.'

When I run 'radiusd -X' I get the error:

```
Could not link driver rlm_sql_postgresql: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-
server/3.0.11/lib/rlm_sql_postgresql.dylib, 6): image not found 
Make sure it (and all its dependent libraries!) are in the search path of your system's ld
/usr/local/Cellar/freeradius-server/3.0.11/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sql[20]: Instantiation failed for module "sql"
```

When I look in the folder 3.0.11/lib there is indeed no such file called rlm_sql_postgresql.dylib.

Any ideas on this? Should I be generating this file somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means when configure was run for freeradius, it didn't pick up libpq.

Apparently `brew install postgresql` will pull down libpq and its development headers.

Remove freeradius, install postgresql, install freeradius with `brew install --build-from-source freeradius-server`

It *should* (unless the homebrew people have gone out of their way to break things), install the postgresql driver.